# Is there a guaranteed ordering in the writing of Characteristics to Peripherals?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to understand if there is any ordering in how BLE packets are sent from an iOS device using CoreBluetooth to connected Peripherals.

I have two Peripherals connected to an iOS device, and are able to write to a Characteristic on both Peripherals successfully. This Characteristic has the effect of taking a signal high or low upon the Peripherals.

I am turning the Characteristics on in an ordered fashion (A then B), and then turning them off in the same order.

```
toggleState(peripheral: primary, stateChar: g1StateChar, state: true)
toggleState(peripheral: secondary, stateChar: g2StateChar, state: true)
sleep(1)
toggleState(peripheral: primary, stateChar: g1StateChar, state: false)
toggleState(peripheral: secondary, stateChar: g2StateChar, state: false)

func toggleState(peripheral: CBPeripheral, stateChar: CBCharacteristic, state: Bool) {

    var devState = "S"

    //S for Stop, A for Active
    if(state){
        devState = "S"
    } else {
        devState = "A"
    }

    let newState = Data(devState.utf8)
    //Transmit new State of System

    peripheral.writeValue(newState, for: stateChar, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
}
```

What I expect to see is the signal associated with A going high, followed by the signal associated with B, separated by about 7.5ms as the Peripherals are programmed to use a 7.5ms connection interval.

What is actually observed is many times the above is the case, but in others Signal B goes high first, followed by A going high 22ms later.